# How to do a simple loop in iMacros

Tags: imacros

I'm just getting started using iMacros, and am struggling to write effective loops.

The code I want to execute is as follows (imagine that example.com takes you to a page with a series of buttons, and when you click each button you are given a further button -- a "sub-button" -- to click:

```
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:"First main button"
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:SubButton
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:"Second main button"
TAG POS=4 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:SubButton
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:"Third main button"
TAG POS=6 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:SubButton
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:"Fourth main button"
TAG POS=8 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:SubButton
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:"Fifth main button"
TAG POS=10 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:SubButton
```

etc. etc., with the POS value for SubButton increasing by 2 each time. How can I write this so that when I run the macro in a loop, the current loop iteration is used to generate the POS value? i.e., how do I set the POS value as 2i?

Comment: use play loop option

Comment: Thank you, can you be a bit more specific? If you could rewrite the above code so that it includes a loop that would be great :)

Comment: there is no loop internally you have to use loop option or js

Comment: for getting loop index use {{!LOOP}}

Answer (score 0):

use this js

```
wds = ['first','second']


iimDisplay("looper");

for (index in wds ) {
    iimSet("index", index);
    iimSet("words", wds[index]);
    retcode = iimPlay("yourmacropath",60);
    if (retcode < 0) {              
        errtext = iimGetLastError();
        alert(errtext);
        break;
    }
}

iimDisplay("Script completed.");
```

macro content

```
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:{{!words}}
TAG POS={{!index}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:SubButton
```